# How to display row contents in dialog box when clicking on the row

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I am new to javascript and jQuery. Yesterday I asked this question [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12308198/append-row-from-user-input-javascript) and found out how to add rows to table from input values. So now I have a table which will create new rows which will display user inputs. Today I am trying to find out how I can display the row contents in a dialog box when I click on a particular row. Any leads, advice, tutes will be useful. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a start:

Whenever the user clicks on this row, the html will be displayed in the javascript default dialog box.

If you want to do more sophisticated processing you could call a function that will process the rows content using the following:

```
<script type="text/javascript>
    function processRow(row){
         ...
    }

</script>
...

<tr onclick="processRow(this)">
```

Comment: Thank you, this helped me get started.